# Link to FB business opens Meta app instead of a new tab in browser on a mobile device

Tags: html, facebook, hyperlink

The website has a link like so:

```
<a href="https://business.facebook.com/some_part" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

"some_part" is unique to each user, linking them to a specific asset they own. This works fine on desktop browsers. However, clicking this link on a mobile device that has "Meta business suite" app installed, it opens the Meta app index page, without taking the user where they need to go, as the app does not have such functionality. Strangely, holding "link" and clicking "Open in new tab" works just fine and opens in the mobile browser.

Any ideas how to prevent the Meta business app from interfering with links to "business.facebook.com"?

Tested on iPhone and Android with same result